# How do I add Restart in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android

I just create a simple Quiz App. And it's working cool. Even, I just add **"Close Application"** under **AlertDialog** when you reached the end of the question with your score. But I want to add one more function beside Close Application. I want to add **"Restart"** So when user click Restart then they can play quiz game again. How do I Do that?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // TODO: Declare member variables here:
    Button mTrueButton;
    Button mFalseButton;
    TextView mQuestionTextView;
    int mIndex;
    int mQuestion;
    int mScore;
    TextView mScoreTextView;
    ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    // TODO: Uncomment to create question bank
    private TrueFalse[] mQuestionBank = new TrueFalse[] {
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_1, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_2, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_3, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_4, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_5, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_6, false),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_7, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_8, false),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_9, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_10, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_11, false),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_12, false),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_13,true)
    };

    // TODO: Declare constants here
    final int PROGRESS_BAR_INCREMENT = (int)Math.ceil (100.0/ mQuestionBank.length);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
        mScoreTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        mQuestion = mQuestionBank[mIndex].getQuestionID();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(mQuestion);

        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(true);
                updateQuestion();

            }
        });

        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(false);
                updateQuestion();

            }
        });
    }
    private void updateQuestion(){
        mIndex = (mIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;

        if (mIndex == 0){
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setTitle("Game Over");
            alert.setCancelable(false);
            alert.setMessage("You scored " + mScore + " points!");
            alert.setPositiveButton("Close Application", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            alert.show();
        }


        mQuestion = mQuestionBank[mIndex].getQuestionID();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(mQuestion);
        mScoreTextView.setText("Score " + mScore + "/" + mQuestionBank.length);
        mProgressBar.incrementProgressBy(PROGRESS_BAR_INCREMENT);
    }
    private void checkAnswer(boolean userSelection){
        boolean correctAnswer = mQuestionBank[mIndex].isAnswer();
        if (userSelection == correctAnswer){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.correct_toast,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mScore = mScore + 1;
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.incorrect_toast,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the final result/Solution

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



    // TODO: Declare member variables here:
    Button mTrueButton;
    Button mFalseButton;
    TextView mQuestionTextView;
    int mIndex;
    int mQuestion;
    int mScore;
    TextView mScoreTextView;
    ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    // TODO: Uncomment to create question bank
    private TrueFalse[] mQuestionBank = new TrueFalse[] {
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_1, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_2, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_3, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_4, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_5, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_6, false),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_7, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_8, false),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_9, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_10, true),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_11, false),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_12, false),
            new TrueFalse(R.string.question_13,true)
    };

    // TODO: Declare constants here
    final int PROGRESS_BAR_INCREMENT = (int)Math.ceil (100.0/ mQuestionBank.length);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
        mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
        mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
        mScoreTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        mQuestion = mQuestionBank[mIndex].getQuestionID();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(mQuestion);

        mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(true);
                updateQuestion();

            }
        });

        mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkAnswer(false);
                updateQuestion();

            }
        });
    }
    private void updateQuestion(){
        mIndex = (mIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;

        if (mIndex == 0){
            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alert.setTitle("Game Over");
            alert.setCancelable(false);
            alert.setMessage("You scored " + mScore + " points!");
            alert.setPositiveButton("Close Application", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton("Restart", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    onRestart();
                }
            });
            alert.show();
        }


        mQuestion = mQuestionBank[mIndex].getQuestionID();
        mQuestionTextView.setText(mQuestion);
        mScoreTextView.setText("Score " + mScore + "/" + mQuestionBank.length);
        mProgressBar.incrementProgressBy(PROGRESS_BAR_INCREMENT);
    }
    private void checkAnswer(boolean userSelection){
        boolean correctAnswer = mQuestionBank[mIndex].isAnswer();
        if (userSelection == correctAnswer){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.correct_toast,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mScore = mScore + 1;
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.incorrect_toast,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aah, The Big Nerd Ranch books :) Love them! Doing the one on Front-end Web Development right at this moment! Good luck! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
alert.setNegativeButton("Restart", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        yourRestartFunction();
    }
});
```

-- OR --

```
alert.setNeutralButton("Restart", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        yourRestartFunction();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Joe Please check. It's working good. Thanks again!